# Actions must be plain objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to make simple react-redux app without api call localstorage type app but when I call an actions it will not update my state and even showing this error too. The thing I know that middleware is required when you need to call api and manage that data from api. This will work like a bridge but I'm not calling any api so why am I getting this error?

Here is my code

```js
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import configureStore from './store/configureStore'
import AppRouter from './routers/Approuter'
import { addReport } from './actions/reportsaction'
import { setTextFilter } from './actions/reportfilters'
import App from './App'
import getvisibilityfilter from './selectors/reportsvisibilty'
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
const store = configureStore();
console.log(store)
store.dispatch(addReport({patient_name:'Akki Sharma'}));
store.dispatch(setTextFilter({text:'akki'}));
const state = store.getState();
console.log(state)
// const visiblereport = getvisibilityfilter(state.reports, state.filters)
// console.log(visiblereport)


ReactDOM.render( <AppRouter/>, document.getElementById('app'));

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

addReport.js

```
export const addReport = ({
    r_id = 0
    , reg_date = ''
    , reg_no = 0
    , patient_name = ''
    , gender = ''
    , age = 0
    , refer_by = ''
    , test_request = ''
    , report_status = ''
    , total_amt = 0
    , receipt_amt = 0
    , bal_amt = 0
} = {}) => {
    return {
        type: 'ADD_REPORTS'
        , reports: {
            r_id
            , reg_date
            , reg_no
            , patient_name
            , gender
            , age
            , refer_by
            , test_request
            , report_status
            , total_amt
            , receipt_amt
            , bal_amt
        }
    }
}
setTextFilter: export const setTextFilter = (text = '') => {
    return {
        type: 'SET_TEXT_FILTER'
        , text
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code for `addReport and  setTextFilter`

Comment: addReport.js : export  const addReport = ({
r_id = 0,
reg_date ='',
reg_no = 0,
patient_name ='',
gender ='',
age = 0,
refer_by = '',
test_request = '',
report_status = '',
total_amt = 0,
receipt_amt = 0,
bal_amt = 0
} = {}
) => {
    return {
type: 'ADD_REPORTS',
reports: {
r_id,
reg_date,
reg_no,
patient_name,
gender,
age,
refer_by,
test_request,
report_status,
total_amt,
receipt_amt,
bal_amt
}
    }
}  setTextFilter :export const setTextFilter = (text = '') => {
    return {
    type:'SET_TEXT_FILTER',
    text
}
}

Comment: It doesn't update because your action is `ADD_REPORTS` and not `ADD_REPORT`

Comment: What is `setTextFilter: export const`? I havent seen something like this

Comment: Thanx Shubham for your help by correcting my silly mistake

Comment: Can be closed under the official close reason: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._